# How do I install VMware tools on Ubuntu 9.10 Server 64 bits with no GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-fusion

Host OS: Mac OS X 10.5 with VMware Fusion 2.0.6

I have successfully installed and running Ubuntu 9.10 server edition on a VMware guest.  When I select my VM and click Install VMware Tools, nothing happens.  Is there a way to install VMware tools through the CLI only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.

The VMware Tools are delivered on an ISO file you can hook up to your guest's CD-ROM.

1. In Fusion, connect /Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/isoimages/linux.iso to the CD-ROM for you Ubuntu guest.
2. In the guest, open a terminal and log in as root (or do the rest with sudo)
3. Mount the cdrom someplace like /mnt/cdrom/
4. Copy the tools tar.gz file from /mnt/cdrom/ to someplace like /tmp, untar it and run /tmp/vmware-tools/vmware-install.pl

Answer (score 6):

Kbyrd's answer is correct, but here are the actual commands:

After you click `Install VMware Tools` (note that the first step may be optional, depending on what you've got installed and the version of VMware that you are using):

```
 jed@host:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
 jed@host:~$ mount /cdrom
 jed@host:~$ cp /cdrom/VMware* /tmp
 jed@host:~$ umount /cdrom
 jed@host:~$ cd /tmp
 jed@host:~$ tar xvfz VMware*.gz
 jed@host:~$ cd vmware-tools-distrib/
 jed@host:~$ sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

Answer yes to the questions and you should be all set.

Good luck,

--jed

Comment: @jed: Thanks, this really should be the accepted answer. I was simply answering off the top of my head without access to an actual Linux guest.

Comment: @kbyrd, Nah, yours was a good answer, and you got there first. I just happened to have access to a system that I've done this on recently and figured I'd record the steps here for posterity. Thanks though.